# Adjust color temperature or warmth in Three.js

Tags: javascript, dom, three.js, light

I have created a small room type scene in three.js where I have added few lights.

I have also added features like exposure, power, height at which it is located.

Here is the [link](http://techreise.com/webgl_lights_physical.html) where you can see what is done till now.

Now I want to add feature to adjust temperature of the light.

how can I do that?

Comment: Just change the color of your lights?

Comment: @somethinghere Which colors define the temperature properties?

Comment: Just the general light colors, so a light like `new THREE.SpotLight( 0xff0000 )` will be redder and therefor warmer etc... It's just your light color that defines its 'temperature'. For a slider that steps between 0 and 1 your could do `light.color.set( 0xffffff ).lerp( 0xff0000, amount )`

Comment: @somethinghere I am new to three.js so can you tell me what that amount parameter of lerp will do in above line?

Comment: If the value is between `0` and `1` it will find the value in between, so in this case it will return the color in between fully white and fully red. (Like `.5` will be exactly between the two colors). It's a _linear interpolation_ of the two values.

Comment: @somethinghere I understood now, thanks for help man I will try this solution.

Comment: @somethinghere I tried this but on change event screen goes completely dark. Here is my html tag :                                         

<input type="range" id="colors" name="colors" min="0" max="1" step="any" onchange="changeColor();">

And here is my JS function : 

 function changeColor() {
            var lightColor = document.getElementById("colors").value;
            alert(lightColor);
            bulbLight.color.setHex( 0x00bfff ).lerp( 0xff0000, lightColor );
        }

Comment: I will also need some js as the input looks fine.

Comment: function changeColor() {
 var lightColor = document.getElementById("colors").value; bulbLight.color.setHex( 0x00bfff ).lerp( 0xff0000, lightColor );
}

Comment: Ow sorry, replace the ‘0xff0000 with ‘new THREE.Color( 0xff0000 )’, you need a THREE.Color, not just a hex value., three doesnt know what to do with that.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the below snippet as an example:

```js
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer;
var scene = new THREE.Scene;
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera;
var cube = new THREE.Mesh( new THREE.BoxGeometry, new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial );
var spot = new THREE.SpotLight;
var inputs = [ ...document.querySelectorAll( 'input' ) ];
var destinationColor = new THREE.Color( 1, 1, 1 );
var fps = 1000 / 16;
var width = innerWidth;
var height = innerHeight / 2;

renderer.setSize( width, height );

camera.aspect = innerWidth / height;
camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
camera.position.set( 0, 0, 10 );
camera.lookAt( scene.position );

spot.position.set( 0, 0, 50 );
spot.lookAt( scene.position );

scene.add( cube, spot );

function inputChanged( event ){

  destinationColor.fromArray( inputs.map(input => input.value) );

}

function update(){

  spot.color.lerp( destinationColor, fps / 1000 );

  renderer.render( scene, camera );

}

document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

inputs.forEach(input => input.addEventListener( 'change', inputChanged ));

setInterval( update, fps );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/92/three.min.js"></script>

R <input type="range" min="0" max="1" step=".1" value="1" />
G <input type="range" min="0" max="1" step=".1" value="1" />
B <input type="range" min="0" max="1" step=".1" value="1" />
```

*Tested on r92, works on Chrome.*